Given an active filter or any sort of operational amplifier with finite open loop gain, is feedback factor accounted for in the standard gain formula?
To be honest I don't know exactly what I'm calculating here, I know why I'm doing this but I don't know what this expression for gain is exactly.
If I was dealing with an ideal opamp, it's consider a virtual short and proceed from \$ V^+=V^- \$. However, if I'm dealing with an opamp that has finite open loop gain I'd proceed with \$ V_o = A_o(V^+ - V^-) \$.
Now, say that I have the following expressions for \$V^+ \$ and \$V^-\$:
\begin{cases}
V^+ = V_i\frac{R}{R+\frac{1}{sC}}) \\
V^-=\frac{1}{2}V_o
\end{cases}
Substituting in the first expression for \$V_o\$:
$$
V_o = A_o(Vi\frac{sCR}{sCR+1}-\frac{1}{2}V_o)
$$
I'll skip the algebra, but the transfer function found from this expression should be:
$$
\frac{V_o}{V_i} = \frac{sCRA_o}{(sCR+1)(1+\frac{A_o}{2})}
$$
What I don't understand is: what exactly is this transfer function? Is it the transfer function for the open loop, or is it the overall gain (I'm assuming closed loop = overall gain)? Is this expression the same as \$A_{CL} = \frac{A_o}{1+\beta A_o} \$?
I've been told that it is, however I'm confused: assuming there would be active elements (capacitors or inductors) in the circuit, but not in the feedback network, and having a finite value for \$A_o\$, like in this circuit for example

If the transfer function found through \$ V_o = A_o(V^+ - V^-) \$ is indeed equal to \$ A_{CL}=\frac{A_o}{1+\beta A_o} \$, then the feedback factor here should be \$ \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_3} \$, plugging it into the expression for \$A_{CL}\$ I'd get \$A_{CL} \approx 0.99 \$ which is the closed loop gain, but where did the rest of the circuit go?
I'm assuming that because of this reason they're not the same expressions, and if they're indeed different, how do they come into play together?
EDIT: This is how I found that expression for the transfer function, there was an error in the numerator and I was missing \$A_o\$, sorry!
$$
V_o = A_o(V_i \frac{sCR}{sCR+1}- \frac{1}{2}V_o) 
$$
$$
V_o + \frac{A_oV_o}{2} = \frac{sCR}{sCR+1}A_oV_i
$$
$$
V_o(1 + \frac{A_o}{2})=\frac{sCR}{sCR+1}A_oV_i
$$
$$
\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{sCRA_o}{(sCR+1)(1+\frac{A_o}{2})}
$$

Only Vio and Iin are neglected. If Aol is infinite does your formula look OK when you skip the algebra? https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Operational_amplifier#Negative-feedback_applications   then Read the wiki and restate your question.

user4.., Show your work. You have a wrong result for the transfer function. (Even a simple sanity test shows that much.) So don't skip showing us how you got it. We can't help you spot your error, otherwise.

Done! I think the error was a missing Ao in the numerator, don't know if there's anything else that's off, but thanks for the help!

you said "I'd get ACL≈0.99"... How?

A first-order high-pass transfer function in s-space may be expressed in either one of the following forms:
$$\begin{align*}H_s&=A\cdot\frac{s}{s+\omega_{_0}}\\\\&=A\cdot\frac{\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}}{\frac{s}{\omega_{_0}}+1}\end{align*}$$
In your case, using KCL I would find that \$A=\frac{A_{_0}}{1+\beta\cdot A_{_0}}\$, \$\beta=\frac{R_2}{R_2+R_3}\$ and \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{R_1\,\cdot\, C_1}\$.
(Note that in your terms: \$A_{_\text{CL}}=A\$.)
If you need any confirmation of the above, algebraically, then I'll use SymPy:
# Solve using KCL:
PlusNode = Eq( Vp/R1 + Vp*s*C1, Vi*s*C1 )
MinusNode = Eq( Vm/R2 + Vm/R3, Vo/R3 )
OutputNode = Eq( Vo/R3, Vm/R3 + Io )
OpampBehavior = Eq( Vo, A0*(Vp-Vm) )
solve([ PlusNode, MinusNode, OutputNode, OpampBehavior ], [ Io, Vm, Vp, Vo ])[Vo]/Vi
A0*C1*R1*s*(R2 + R3)/((C1*R1*s + 1)*(A0*R2 + R2 + R3))

# Expand the assertions I made above to see if my work matches the KCL result:
beta = R2/(R2+R3)
ACL = A0/(1+beta*A0)
omega0 = 1/R1/C1
simplify(ACL*s/(s+w0))
A0*C1*R1*s*(R2 + R3)/((C1*R1*s + 1)*(A0*R2 + R2 + R3))

As you can see, the result is the same.
